# Is Height lengthening haram

Tags: halal-haram

Height lengthening, also known as limb lengthening or leg lengthening, is a medical procedure that involves lengthening a person's bones to increase their height. This procedure is typically done by cutting the bone and inserting an implant that gradually pulls the two pieces of bone apart, allowing new bone to grow and fill the gap.

Comment: there is a hadith in which it is reported the prophet cursed the women who have their teeth separated, because it is changing the creation of Allah. Don't you reckon limb lengthening is a few orders of magnitude above teeth separation in severity ?